# appending command name to files python3

Tags: python-3.x

While learning through the network automation with python, I have created a script to capture the few network switch details with some sorts of commands. i have explicitely kept the commands in `commands.txt` and login credentilas in a file `devices.json` in a Jason format to pick it from and when i run this it works as expected by creating a file with command out details with time stamp.

What i Want: As i have `commands.txt` file which has diffrent commands,  where i would like to have an idea of creating a separate file for each command which i have into `commands.txt`. as of now everything getting captured to a single file, desired example ..

```
prod-stvdx-sw_vcs_details.txt-Apr-10-2018:12:53
prod-stvdx-sw_vcs.txt-Apr-10-2018:12:53
prod-stvdx-sw_fabric_trunk.txt-Apr-10-2018:12:53
```

Below is the script version:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import json
import netmiko
import signal
import sys
import time

timestamp = time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y:%H:%M')

signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)  # IOError: Broken pipe
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)  # KeyboardInterrupt: Ctrl-C


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Usage: cmdrunner.py commands.txt devices.json')
    exit()

netmiko_exceptions = (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException,
                      netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException)

#username, password = getPass.get_credentials()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as cmd_file:
    commands = cmd_file.readlines()

with open(sys.argv[2]) as dev_file:
     devices = json.load(dev_file)

for device in devices:
    #device['username'] = username
    #device['password'] = password
    try:
        print('~' * 79)
        print('Connecting to device:', device['ip'])
        connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
        filename = connection.base_prompt + '.txt' + '-' + timestamp
        with open(filename, 'w') as out_file:
            for command in commands:
                out_file.write('++++ Output of ' + command + '\n\n')
                out_file.write(connection.send_command(command) + '\n\n')
        connection.disconnect()
    except netmiko_exceptions as e:
        print('Failed to ', device['ip'], e)
```

My `commands.txt` File:

```
$ cat commands.txt
show vcs details
show vcs
show fabric islports
show fabric isl
show fabric trunk
show logging raslog
show version
show ip int brief
```

Run

```
$ ./brocade_2.py commands.txt devices.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 moli moli 286K Apr 10 12:53 prod-stvdx-sw.txt-Apr-10-2018:12:53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if I understand correctly, you want to capture the output of each command in a separate file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import json
import netmiko
import signal
import sys
import time

timestamp = time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y:%H:%M')

signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)  # IOError: Broken pipe
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)  # KeyboardInterrupt: Ctrl-C


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Usage: cmdrunner.py commands.txt devices.json')
    exit()

netmiko_exceptions = (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException,
                      netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException)

#username, password = getPass.get_credentials()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as cmd_file:
    commands = cmd_file.readlines()

with open(sys.argv[2]) as dev_file:
     devices = json.load(dev_file)

for device in devices:
    #device['username'] = username
    #device['password'] = password
    try:
        print('~' * 79)
        print('Connecting to device:', device['ip'])
        connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
        for command in commands:
            filename = connection.base_prompt +'-'+ command+'.txt' + '-' + timestamp
            with open(filename, 'w') as out_file:
                out_file.write('++++ Output of ' + command + '\n\n')
                out_file.write(connection.send_command(command) + '\n\n')
        connection.disconnect()
    except netmiko_exceptions as e:
        print('Failed to ', device['ip'], e)
```

Comment: I dont have luxury to test above code but it should work.

Comment: Are you looking to append the date time as well ?

Comment: Rehan, that works same way as it is. yes i nedd date & time as well.

Comment: You mean nothing changed ?

Comment: Yes, true. creating a single file as it was before!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168622/discussion-between-rehan-azher-and-krock1516).